# Horizontal scroll not working on a div element

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, overflow

@Here, I'm trying to create horizontal scrolling for a div element for my application. The div element consists of ul li element and some other div tags for my requirement. The Ul li elements are dynamically added inside the parent div element.

Although I could get the vertical scrolling working properly and my horizontal scrolling is displayed using overflow-x: scroll. I am not able to scroll it, the ul li elements gets distorted. I have set a predefined width of 700px for the div container also. Its like the horizontal scrolling is disabled. I am not using overflow anywhere else in the application

```
<div class="org-chart" appOrgachart [empArr]="employees" [orgaArr]="orgaArr" *ngIf="employees.length>0 && !isLoading">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let emp of empArr">
      <div class="user">
       <div class="name">{{emp.empname}}</div>
        <div class="role">{{emp.empdesgname}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS file:

```
.org-chart {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 29px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 400px;
    width: 65%;
    transform: translateY(12%);
}
```

Comment: If the width of the container and the width of your inner hierarchy matches then only you will be able to see horizontal scrolling. Check this by decreasing the width to 50% (half of the page). You should be able to see it..

Comment: I have these ul li elements under the container. I tried giving width for my ul li. But still I am not able to get horizontal scroll working

Comment: If I reduce the width to 50%, the ul li order gets distorted as you can see in my image but I am not getting the scroll. :(

Comment: There are couple of things you need to consider when you need scroll, if you would like to share some code then we will be happy to help you.

Comment: probably because your container is flex - does it need to be?

Comment: i tried changing that too inline-block as well @Pete

Comment: Then you are going to have to create a [mcve] as with what you have shown it is hard to say what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, providing `overflow-x: scroll !important;` is big `no no` from me, it should be the last option for you to use.

now coming to your requirement, you need to specifically provide `overflow-x: scroll` if you give `overflow:auto` it automatically gives you a scroll when needed.

**now when is it??**

when the `height` and `width` is more than the browser size that is when you will get the `scrolling` feature.

if you need a scroll within browser size then, decrease the width of the `container` and apply `overflow:auto;` that should give you a scroll on sight.

**here is the example of what I am saying:**

so what does it mean is when you want a scroll within the browser then you should have a `child` class and the width of that class should be less w.r.t the content so that it can overflow.

```css
.org-chart {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 29px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*Main container */
  height: 300px;
  width: 65%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  /* you should have another width inside main container */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="org-chart" appOrgachart [empArr]="employees" [orgaArr]="orgaArr" *ngIf="employees.length>0 && !isLoading">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let emp of empArr">
      <div class="user">
        <div class="name">{{emp.empname}}</div>
        <div class="role">{{emp.empdesgname}}</div>
        <div class="content">Notice that the text-align-last property sets the alignment for all last lines within the selected element. So, if you have a with three paragraphs in it, text-align-last will apply to the last line of EACH of the paragraphs. To use text-align-last
          on only the last paragraph in the container, you can use :last child, see example below. Notice that the text-align-last property sets the alignment for all last lines within the selected element. So, if you have a with three paragraphs in it,
          text-align-last will apply to the last line of EACH of the paragraphs. To use text-align-last on only the last paragraph in the container, you can use :last child, see example below. Notice that the text-align-last property sets the alignment
          for all last lines within the selected element. So, if you have a with three paragraphs in it, text-align-last will apply to the last line of EACH of the paragraphs. To use text-align-last on only the last paragraph in the container, you can
          use :last child, see example below. Notice that the text-align-last property sets the alignment for all last lines within the selected element. So, if you have a with three paragraphs in it, text-align-last will apply to the last line of EACH
          of the paragraphs. To use text-align-last on only the last paragraph in the container, you can use :last child, see example below.</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried removing the overflow-x: scroll and overflow-y:scroll and replaced them with overflow:auto. But nothing changed for me. It still gets distorted

Comment: what about vertical scroll you need that as well?

Comment: yes. else, the components are overflowing out of the cointainer.

Comment: @Owner I just updated an answer what I am trying to say, hope you may get something to start with.

Comment: I think I understand, so I had position:relative for the Ul list element. I removed it and added a width of 1000px to the Ul element and the scroll appeared. But the left most element gets hidden or cut into half. Let me see if I can have some more css to it to resolve it

Comment: Great! glad that my 2 cents helped you. Yeah if you understood the concepts then you will crack in some time. Decrease the `Child` width and use `padding` and `margin` will help you and also use border to the `child` class so that you will know what you're dealing with. Cheers.

Comment: You can vote and accept it as answer if you think if it is worth doing it!

Answer (score 0):

apply max-width property as 64% and overflow:auto